# Why is seraphim a plural of seraph?

Tags: american-english, british-english, irregular-plurals

This pluralization pattern is highly unlike those I found in English, such as those ending in -(e)s and ones that were technically borrowed from Latin and Greek, thus following different patterns that may confuse English speakers themselves.

Comment: See also _Cherubim, Hasidim_, and _goyim_. Same suffix, Hebrew masculine plural.

Answer (score 8):

That is because seraph derives from Hebrew, and the plural male form in Hebrew ends with the syllable "im".

etymonline.com -

seraph (n.)
1667, first used by Milton (probably on analogy of cherub/cherubim), back-formed singular from Old English seraphim (plural), from Late Latin seraphim, from Greek seraphim, **from Hebrew** seraphim

Answer (score 4):

[Seraph](https://www.etymonline.com/word/seraph) is actually a back formation of seraphim, first used by British  author Milton:

> 1667, first used by Milton (probably on analogy of cherub/cherubim), back-formed singular from Old English seraphim (plural), from Late Latin seraphim, from Greek seraphim, from Hebrew seraphim (only in Isaiah vi), ***plural of *saraph (which does not occur in the Bible),*** probably literally "the burning one," from saraph "it burned." Seraphs were traditionally regarded as burning or flaming angels, though the word seems to have some etymological sense of "flying," perhaps from confusion with the root of Arabic sharafa "be lofty." Some scholars identify it with a word found in other passages interpreted as "fiery flying serpent."

Comment: Just because a word doesn't occur in the Bible, it doesn't mean it's not a valid Hebrew word.